# Build a .NET 7 REST API to parse data from either a CSV or a JSON file

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-7.0

I am currently working with a codebase that is hard-coded to load data from a CSV file.

The app now needs the ability to support loading data from additional file formats, e.g. XML or JSON files.

I want to create a simple solution that doesn't impact a significant part of the codebase. The choice of file format can be made in configuration or dynamically chosen at `Startup`, but will not change once the application is
running.

Can someone recommend a clean pattern to achieve this goal?

My early idea is to have my API endpoint work with a Service that will run a check to see what the desired data format is set to in `appsettings.json`. The Service will use `IConfiguration` to access the value and, dependent on what the value is, it will then use the relevant Repository to interact with the data.

For instance, if the field in `appsettings.json` is set to `XML`, my Service will call `XMLDataRepository`. Alternatively, if it is set to `csv` I will call a `CSVDataRepository`.

My service constructor will then look like:

```
public class MyService
{

   private readonly IConfiguration _config;
   private readonly IXMLDataRepository _xmlDataRepository;
   private readonly ICSVDataRepository _csvDataRepository;

   public MyService(
        IConfiguration config, 
        IXMLDataRepository xmlDataRepository,
        ICSVDataRepository csvDataRepository)
   {
        _config = config;
        _xmlDataRepository = xmlDataRepository;
        _csvDataRepository = csvDataRepository;

   }

   public MyResponseModel GetAllX()
   {
       // run check in `appsettings.json` on desired data format
       // dependent on value, use matching repository

       return _xmlDataRepository.GetAllX();
   }


}
```

I could probably have all of my repositories inherit from a single, base class which may add flexibility.

I am open to ideas. Any thoughts?

Comment: This question is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, but may be acceptable at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question will likely be closed as opinion-based, because there are literally hundreds of ways you can solve this particular problem, and Stack Overflow is intended for questions that can be definitively and objectively answered. That said, because your question is head and shoulders ahead of most others asked here nowadays, I am happy to leave an answer that will hopefully be useful to you even if closure occurs. Note that all code provided is pseudo-code!

You're on the right track - what you've come up with is a well-known software design pattern known as the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). However, we can make this code cleaner and simpler by moving the check for which type to use to the stage at which the DI container is built, instead of in the service. Start with a single base interface:

```
interface IDataRepository
{
    MyResponseModel GetAllX();
}
```

that is implemented by both your XML- and CSV-reading interfaces and implementations:

```
interface IXmlDataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    ...
}

interface ICSVDataRepository : IDataRepository
{
    ...
}

...

class XmlDataRepository : IXmlDataRepository
{
    MyResponseModel GetAllX()
    {
        // get via xml
    }
}

class CsvDataRepository : ICsvDataRepository
{
    MyResponseModel GetAllX()
    {
        // get via csv
    }
}
```

In your dependency setup, register the lowest-level interface with the appropriate implementation from config:

```
Type implementationType;

if (_configuration.UseXml)
{
    implementationType = typeof(XmlDataRepository);
}
else
{
    implementationType = typeof(CsvDataRepository);
}

services.AddScoped<IDataRepository>(implementationType);
```

and finally, inject that common interface into your service and call the method:

```
class MyService
{
    private readonly IDataRepository _dataRepository;

    MyService(IDataRepository dataRepository)
    {
        _dataRepository = dataRepository;
    }

    MyResponseModel GetAllX()
        => _dataRepository.GetAllX();
}
```

There are some concerns to be aware of though. If you find yourself adding parameters to the base `IDataRepository.GetAllX` method just to satisfy either the XML or CSV implementation, or have to call it in different ways for different implementations, that likely implies those implementations have diverged enough that the strategy pattern is no longer appropriate - because you're now trying to make the interface fit the implementation, not the other way around.